# Mongo DB: Sorting by the number of matches

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I have an array of objects, and I want to query in a MongoDB collection for documents that have elements that match any objects in my array of objects.

For example:

```
var objects = ["52d58496e0dca1c710d9bfdd", "52d58da5e0dca1c710d9bfde", "52d91cd69188818e3964917b"];

db.scook.recipes.find({products: { $in: objects }}
```

However, I want to know if I can sort the results by the number of matches in MongoDB.

For example, at the top will be the "recipe" that has exactly three elements matches: `["52d58496e0dca1c710d9bfdd", "52d58da5e0dca1c710d9bfde", "52d91cd69188818e3964917b"]`.

The second selected has two recipes: i.e. `["52d58496e0dca1c710d9bfdd", "52d58da5e0dca1c710d9bfde"]`, and the third one only one: i.e. `["52d58496e0dca1c710d9bfdd"]`

It would be great if you could get the number of items it had.

Comment: I think you have three options here: MongoDB Aggregation Framework, MongoDB Map-Reduce, and manipulating the data in your server. If I have time, I'll try to answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

By using the aggregation framework, I think that you should be able to get what you need by the following MongoDB query. However, if you're using Mongoose, you'll have to convert this to a Mongoose query. I'm not certain this will work exactly as is, so you may need to play with it a little to make it right. Also, this answer hinges on whether or not you can use the `$or` operator inside of the `$project` operator and that it will return true. If that doesn't work, I think you'll need to use map-reduce to get what you need or do it server side.

```
db.recipes.aggregate(
    // look for matches
    { $match : { products : { $or : objects }}},
    // break apart documents to by the products subdocuments
    { $unwind : "$products" },
    // search for matches in the sub documents and add productMatch if a match is found
    { $project : {
        desiredField1 : 1,
        desiredField2 : 1,
        products : 1,
        // this may not be a valid comparison, but should hopefully
        // be true or 1 if there is a match
        productMatch : { "$products" : { $or : objects }}
    }},
    // group the unwound documents back together by _id
    { $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        products : { $push : "$products" },
        // count the matched objects
        numMatches : { $sum : "$productMatch" },
        // increment by 1 for each product
        numProducts : { $sum : 1 }
    }},
    // sort by descending order by numMatches
    { $sort : { numMatches : -1 }}
)
```